# handling JsonP callback

Tags: jquery, json

I am getting json data as a response back from the server. I want to parse this JSON data and embed all the data into a pop up window.

I getting this a reponse from the server

```
jsonp1308824138177("<div class="widget-cntr"><div class="image-container"> </div></div>")


var validate_url='http://xxx.com/cid='+cid+'&url='+currentUrl+'&wid='+wid+'&imgW='+imgW+'&jsoncallback=?';
$.getJSON(validate_url, jQuery.proxy(this, 'show_wid_results'));


function show_wid_results(data){
alert(data);
}
```

output shows a error token expression <

Answer (score 1):

<strike>it needs to be</strike>

jsonp1308824138177(" ")

however it isn't JSON, so it's completelly wrong!

Answer (score 0):

```
jsonp1308824138177("<div class="widget-cntr"><div class="image-container"> </div></div>")
```

use ' istead of " in a string like this

```
jsonp1308824138177("<div class='widget-cntr'><div class='image-container'> </div></div>")
```

check this it works fine.....

Comment: actually proper json format is that jsoxp130("{ 'result':'pass', 'return' : '1000' }");